# Should I be concerned over an event being added more than once?

Tags: c#, game-engine

I have a class instance which contains an event type. This event will be called if `value` is changed. I also contain a seperate function in `Menu` which must be called every time the program performs an action (***changes menu screens***). Should I be concerned over multiple `onChange` events occuring (or will multple onChange additions even occur)?

```
public class ValueHolder<T>
{
    public virtual T Value { /*get set stuff*/ }

    public event Action<T> onChange;
    // other necessary code
}

public class Menu
{
    ValueHolder<int> value = new ValueHolder<int>();

    void MenuChanged()
    {
        value.onChange += (i) =>
        {
            // do stuff
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Should value be static?

Comment: I have omitted a huge amount of detail for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Please simplify it as much as possible, but not more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your MenuChanged method will be called will add new anonymous method to the event invocation list, so yes, all of them would be called then.

Comment: You say `anonymous`. If I define an action `public Action something = () => { /*doSomething*/ }`, will it still continuously add? Additionally, should I truly be concerned?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to reach. I would for sure unsubscribe the previously added method from the event if I don't want it to be called. You can save the last subscriber method in the private field and unsubscribe it when you add new one.